# How to insert a vba code in private macro to command button

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code which involves copying column data from source and pasting in a new workbook. When i run this code through an active x command button in the sheet [in sheet like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7IwZb.png), i get a run time error. I was told to create private module for the sheet and copy paste code there. [in module like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATXK3.png)

But when i save it and click on active x button on the sheet, nothing happens. If i go to de-bugging window and hit F5 or F8, it will run perfectly. What is my mistake? How to make the code inside module attach to the command button?

Here's my code:

```
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim wksSource As Worksheet, wksDest As Worksheet
Dim source1 As Range, target1 As Range, source2 As Range
Dim target2 As Range

Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\catia\Downloads\Raw Data.xlsx"

Set wksSource = Workbooks("2020 Tracker.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet3")
Set wksDest = Workbooks("Raw Data.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1")

lastrow = wksSource.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row

Workbooks("Raw Data.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows("3:" & Rows.Count).ClearContents

Set source1 = wksSource.Range("A2:A" & lastrow)
Set source2 = wksSource.Range("C2:C" & lastrow)

Set target1 = wksDest.Range(Range("B3"), Range("B3").End(xlDown))
Set target2 = wksDest.Range(Range("E3"), Range("E3").End(xlDown))

source1.Copy: target1.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
source2.Copy: target2.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

wksDest.Range("A2").Select
Workbooks("Raw Data.xlsx").Save
Workbooks("Raw Data.xlsx").Close
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question and include your code.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed - just did

Comment: You need to make sure that all `Range` calls are qualified with the worksheet and workbook they are on/in.

Comment: @BigBen - how do i do that? if you mean the vb code has to be in the sheet, then i already tried that before inserting the module

Comment: `Set target1 = wksDest.Range(wksDest.Range("B3"), wksDest.Range("B3").End(xlDown))`

Comment: `Set target2 = wksDest.Range(wksDest.Range("E3"), wksDest.Range("E3").End(xlDown))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to qualify your `Range` calls with the worksheet they are on.

Change

```
Set target1 = wksDest.Range(Range("B3"), Range("B3").End(xlDown))
Set target2 = wksDest.Range(Range("E3"), Range("E3").End(xlDown))
```

to

```
Set target1 = wksDest.Range(wksDest.Range("B3"), wksDest.Range("B3").End(xlDown))
Set target2 = wksDest.Range(wksDest.Range("E3"), wksDest.Range("E3").End(xlDown))
```

Or with a `With...End With` block:

```
With wksDest
    Set target1 = .Range(.Range("B3"), .Range("B3").End(xlDown))
    Set target2 = .Range(.Range("E3"), .Range("E3").End(xlDown))
End With
```

Or since you are pasting special, you can just keep `target1` and `target2` as the first cell of the range:

```
Set target1 = wksDest.Range("B3")
Set target2 = wksDest.Range("E3")
```